# How to fetch details from Application insight in c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

My current requirement is to fetch the Application Insight Data into my application & Use the log data for some of the customized dashboard. Dashboard is 2nd task i can take care. Only the Query is how to fetch logs from Application Insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your best bet is to use the [rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) to access the data.

It uses the same syntax for queries as [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) so if you already have some experience with that it is really easy.

Some basic queries to get you started can be found [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart)

Comment: @lokanathdas what are the other problems you are still facing then?

Comment: Yes its working as expected as i was wondering for this type of API. This holds for certain time range.. so i have done some changes to the API query & its working fine now ....

Comment: Great, feel free to accept this answer as the solution for the question so others know it has been solved.

Comment: Thanks alot Once again.

Comment: @PeterBons Is there a way to monitor the status of App service using Rest API?
Can you please provide which metric to use to get details for Online status and  Uptime percentage for a given duration

Comment: So what is the solution? For A.I. Rest API i only see documentation for Metrics, Events, Query (for requests). How to get logs specifically?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar what do you mean? You can query everything, like traces, exceptions, customevents etc. by sending kusto queries to the api. See https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY and try ' customEvents | limit 10'  for example